# oracle scheduler job not running (after enabling it)

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-scheduler

I created a scheduler job in the following way:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
job_name           =>  'update_sales_1',
job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
job_action         =>  'test_job',
start_date         =>  systimestamp,
repeat_interval  =>  'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=10',
end_date           =>  '20-NOV-2021 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
auto_drop          =>   FALSE,

comments           =>  'My new job');
END;
/
```

The stored procedure `test_job` inserts record into a table.
After creating the JOB, I enabled it and waited for 20 seconds and checked the table.
I do not see the records inserted.

Comment: Does the procedure have a commit following the insert statement?

Comment: Yes it has @Boneist

Comment: What does `USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS` show for your job? Also, what is the `next_run_date` in `USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS` for this job?

Comment: select * from USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS shows no rows selected and next_run_date is 13-JAN-20 06.01.03.000000000 AM -05:00

Comment: What is `13-JAN-20`? 2013-01-20 or 2020-01-13 (or even 0020-01-13, 0013-01-20)? Please output proper format. For `end_date` you should also provide a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value rather than a string.

Comment: What is the status of the job in USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS?

Comment: @ArijitKanrar I do not see status rather enabled is true and state is scheduled. Is this something you wanted? I ran the job manually and sill it is not running.

Comment: Assuming your job has been set up correctly, perhaps it's something else (such as parameters that are set too low for the job to be able to be run). Try working your way through the suggestions in [this FAQ](https://community.oracle.com/thread/648581?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: @Boneist Thanks for the comments, I checked and found job_queue_processes parameter is set to 0. I have asked to make a change and will then test. Hope it will work.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a parameter `enabled => TRUE`, default is `FALSE`. 
If you want to enable the job after creating it you can also use: 
 
`DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE(name => 'update_sales_1');`

If your job did run, and you don't see anything that has happened you might can look at the job run details if something went wrong: 
`SELECT * FROM dba_scheduler_job_run_details WHERE job_name = UPPER('update_sales_1') ORDER BY actual_start_date;`